# Custom UIVisualEffectView with blur is not the same as UINavigationBat blur view

Tags: swift, ios8, uinavigationbar, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I try to extend somehow the UINavigationBar with a UIVisualEffetView.
And the view hieararchy is correct but the blur effect is not the same as in the UINavigationBar.

Here is my POC, you can download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hqa2aiu0imwg8a4/TableViewHeaderWithBlurPOC.zip?dl=0)

As you can see its different, but I dont know why?
Can anybody solved this somehow?

Here is a screenshot:[image]